# cakePHP associated models seems failed on live server

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I am building a website using cakePHP. I understand the principles of cakePHP and the model association well. In this project I have to make some associated models, they are working well on localhost. When I use find method, on localhost I get the result as I expedted (an associative array where keys are model names). On localhost everything works fine. But as I upload it to a live server, everthing goes wrong, and if I use find method here, I get a very strange result: multidimensional arrays, not associative, and there are no model names as keys, but all associated model data are mixed together. I have never seen such "error". But because of this malfunction everything is broken, as I expect a data where I can access information using model names as key. Where I should seek for the solution? Thx for help!

Comment: Any entries on error.log?

Answer (score 0):

It may be issue with PDO extension in your PHP library of server.I faced this issue earlier, when PDO extension was removed from the server and I got all my cakephp applications were messed up. My company provide us new server.

You can check this with checking your phpinfo() and also set the debug mode to 2 and see what is showing up.